# Geting object, both id and value from ngFor on button click angular 6

Tags: angular, angular5, angular6

this is html code

```
<tr>
    <td>Select New Subject:</td>
    <td>
     <Select name="DesiredSubject" [(ngModel)] = "sub" ngDefaultControl>
       <option [value]="0">--Select Subject--</option>
       <option *ngFor ="let subj of subjects" [value]="subj">{{subj.bank_Name}}</option>
     </Select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Action :</td>
    <td><button value="Update Subject" (click)="changeSubject(sub)">Update Subject</button></td>
</tr>
```

and this is my typescript angular class

```
 export class EditSubjectComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

  @Input()
  subject : any;
  sub : any;
  flag : boolean = false;
  subjects : ISubject[];
  constructor(private _QuestionService : QuestionService, private _toastr : ToastrService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
  ngAfterViewInit(){
      this._QuestionService.getSubject().subscribe((data) => {this.subjects = data;});
    }
  changeSubject(value : any){
    this.flag = true;
    console.log(value)
   this._QuestionService.updateSubject(QID,value).subscribe((res) => {this._toastr.success("Subject Changed");
  }, err => {
       this._toastr.error("There is some problem. Please try later")
     });
    this.flag = false;
  }

}
```

and this is what i get in the console log. I mean it is returning a string.

[image]

what am i doing wrong?  and i have updated the code now.

Comment: Where exactly are you calling the `changeSubject ` method?

Comment: Where does this button positioned in your template? Can you please add the complete template of your component for clarity.,

Comment: you are passing only one parameter here `changeSubject(sub)` but this method `changeSubject(value : any, QID : string)` accepts two parameters. and also please share complete code for better understanding.

Comment: `<button value="Update Subject" (click)="changeSubject(sub, subject.id)">Update Subject</button>`
 Sorry myt bad. this is the code. Still not getting any value

Comment: @zaidkhan can you post where exactly the button is implemented ?

Comment: @CruelEngine. I have updated the code.

Comment: I think that your options must be like <option *ngFor ="let subj of subjects" [value]="subj **.bank_id** ">{{subj.bank_Name}} (supouse you have a property bank_id in your "subjects"

Comment: yeah but i want both subj.bank_id and subj.bank_Name

Comment: change this: `[value]="subj"` to this: `[value]="subj.bank_Name"` or some other parameter from subj. it's working here: [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-epxlpg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: your ``sub`` is already available  in the ts ``this.sub`` . Just bind ``(click)`` to your function and inside the function do whatever you want with your ``sub``

Comment: use ``[ngValue]`` instead of ``[value]`` @zaidkhan

Comment: @CruelEngine by using `[ngValue]` i am getting only value which is subject name. but i want both subject value and subject name on button click.

Comment: @zaidkhan i have created an example : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3sedhz

Comment: @CruelEngine. Thanks for the example. Strange, I am doing the same and i am jus getting name not value.

Comment: @zaidkhan can you create a stackblitz example for the issue ?

Comment: @CruelEngine here is the example

https://angular-4uhbk1.stackblitz.io

Comment: @CruelEngine Edit url https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4uhbk1

Comment: @zaidkhan there is a typo in your html : its ``<select>`` and not ``<Select>`` . updated example :  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3b5txx

Comment: @CruelEngine omg. Thanks man. I was searching about this issues all the time. write your answer and i will mark it. Thanks brother

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are binding an object to the `[value]` property . If you want to bind an object to your `option` value , use `[ngValue]` instead of `[value]` .

Also there is a typo in your html where `select` is implemented .  Use `<select>` instead of `<Select>` .

Stackblitz example : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3b5txx